# how to introduce n timepoints for epoch for date java

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink, epoch

How to introduce n timepoints for epoch for date java ?

Suppose I have finite epoch τ = {t0, t1, . . . , tn } of n timepoints for Stream data.

I want to introduce it for Stream data using a (sliding window).

Please Guide?

Comment: Why can't you just use an `IntStream` to provide you with a Stream of integers?

Comment: You proposed a very good option. But can you share any example solution for it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use an `IntStream` to provide you a Stream of ints that allow you to represent τ:

```
final int n = 7;
IntStream.range(0, n).forEachOrdered(i -> {
    System.out.println("t" + i);
});
```

Comment: But I have to process the Longer values in the data streams okay. For that I need some like approach to handle the input stream and pass it in form of τ = {t0, t1, . . . , tn } of n timepoints. For that What should I use?.